How to select Max Percentagematch in the below json response in oracle 19c version?
Sample Json:
In below Json there are multiple percentMatch Keys, I need Max One with respect to data, how can I select that only, please help
{
  "response" :
  [
    {
      "reliability" : "low",
      "percentMatch" : 70,
      "validationNotes" : "House Number, Street Name, Post Directional do not match.",
      "serviceExceptions" : null,
      "validatedAddress" : "1220 COMMERCE ST E",
      "addressLines" :
      {
        "addressLine" :
        [
          "1220 COMMERCE ST E"
        ]
      },
      "addressElements" :
      {
        "housePrefix" : null,
        "houseNumber" : "1220",
        "houseSuffix" : null,
        "streetPreDirectional" : null,
        "streetName" : "COMMERCE",
        "streetSuffix" : "ST",
        "streetPostDirectional" : "E",
        "building" : null,
        "floor" : null,
        "unit" : null,
        "route" : null,
        "box" : null,
        "additionalInfomation" : null,
        "designators" : null,
        "newConstruction" : null,
        "billingOnlyValidation" : null,
        "geoCoordinates" : null
      },
      "locality" :
      {
        "city" : "BUFFALO",
        "county" : "LEON",
        "state" : "TX",
        "country" : "USA",
        "postalCode" : "75831",
        "postalCodeExtension" : ""
      },
      "networkElements" :
      {
        "latitude" : 31.4647364,
        "longitude" : -96.0558224,
        "verticalCoordinates" : 8647.07393488831,
        "horizontalCoordinates" : 3799.4344780898823,
        "geoCode" : 3818500,
        "isIncorporated" : false,
        "lata" : "552",
        "rateCenter" : "BUFFALO",
        "wireCenterClli" : "BFLOTXXA",
        "wireCenterLat" : 31.459261437891254,
        "wireCenterLong" : -96.06751536371283,
        "switchClli" : "BFLOTXXAPS0",
        "ocn" : "1181",
        "ocnName" : "VALOR TELECOMM TX, LD-TX #2 DBA WINDSTREAM COMM SW",
        "ocnCategory" : "ILEC",
        "npa" : "430",
        "nxx" : "221",
        "equipmentType" : "17",
        "isWinILEC" : null,
        "cbsafpcode" : null
      }
    },
    {
      "reliability" : "low",
      "percentMatch" : 66,
      "validationNotes" : "House Number, Pre Directional, Street Name, Post Directional do not match.",
      "serviceExceptions" : null,
      "validatedAddress" : "1220 W COMMERCE ST",
      "addressLines" :
      {
        "addressLine" :
        [
          "1220 W COMMERCE ST"
        ]
      },
      "addressElements" :
      {
        "housePrefix" : null,
        "houseNumber" : "1220",
        "houseSuffix" : null,
        "streetPreDirectional" : "W",
        "streetName" : "COMMERCE",
        "streetSuffix" : "ST",
        "streetPostDirectional" : null,
        "building" : null,
        "floor" : null,
        "unit" : null,
        "route" : null,
        "box" : null,
        "additionalInfomation" : null,
        "designators" : null,
        "newConstruction" : null,
        "billingOnlyValidation" : null,
        "geoCoordinates" : null
      },
      "locality" :
      {
        "city" : "BUFFALO",
        "county" : "LEON",
        "state" : "TX",
        "country" : "USA",
        "postalCode" : "75831",
        "postalCodeExtension" : ""
      },
      "networkElements" :
      {
        "latitude" : 31.4558663,
        "longitude" : -96.0727934,
        "verticalCoordinates" : 8650.052836217625,
        "horizontalCoordinates" : 3801.6306343018737,
        "geoCode" : 3818500,
        "isIncorporated" : null,
        "lata" : "552",
        "rateCenter" : "BUFFALO",
        "wireCenterClli" : "BFLOTXXA",
        "wireCenterLat" : 31.459261437891254,
        "wireCenterLong" : -96.06751536371283,
        "switchClli" : "BFLOTXXAPS0",
        "ocn" : "1181",
        "ocnName" : "VALOR TELECOMM TX, LD-TX #2 DBA WINDSTREAM COMM SW",
        "ocnCategory" : "ILEC",
        "npa" : "430",
        "nxx" : "221",
        "equipmentType" : "17",
        "isWinILEC" : null,
        "cbsafpcode" : null
      }
    }
  ]
}

With the help of below code I am not getting Max PercentageMatch,
WITH JSON_DOC AS
(select '{
  "response" :
  [
    {
      "reliability" : "low",
      "percentMatch" : 70,
      "validationNotes" : "House Number, Street Name, Post Directional do not match.",
      "serviceExceptions" : null,
      "validatedAddress" : "1220 COMMERCE ST E",
      "addressLines" :
      {
        "addressLine" :
        [
          "1220 COMMERCE ST E"
        ]
      },
      "addressElements" :
      {
        "housePrefix" : null,
        "houseNumber" : "1220",
        "houseSuffix" : null,
        "streetPreDirectional" : null,
        "streetName" : "COMMERCE",
        "streetSuffix" : "ST",
        "streetPostDirectional" : "E",
        "building" : null,
        "floor" : null,
        "unit" : null,
        "route" : null,
        "box" : null,
        "additionalInfomation" : null,
        "designators" : null,
        "newConstruction" : null,
        "billingOnlyValidation" : null,
        "geoCoordinates" : null
      },
      "locality" :
      {
        "city" : "BUFFALO",
        "county" : "LEON",
        "state" : "TX",
        "country" : "USA",
        "postalCode" : "75831",
        "postalCodeExtension" : ""
      },
      "networkElements" :
      {
        "latitude" : 31.4647364,
        "longitude" : -96.0558224,
        "verticalCoordinates" : 8647.07393488831,
        "horizontalCoordinates" : 3799.4344780898823,
        "geoCode" : 3818500,
        "isIncorporated" : false,
        "lata" : "552",
        "rateCenter" : "BUFFALO",
        "wireCenterClli" : "BFLOTXXA",
        "wireCenterLat" : 31.459261437891254,
        "wireCenterLong" : -96.06751536371283,
        "switchClli" : "BFLOTXXAPS0",
        "ocn" : "1181",
        "ocnName" : "VALOR TELECOMM TX, LD-TX #2 DBA WINDSTREAM COMM SW",
        "ocnCategory" : "ILEC",
        "npa" : "430",
        "nxx" : "221",
        "equipmentType" : "17",
        "isWinILEC" : null,
        "cbsafpcode" : null
      }
    },
    {
      "reliability" : "low",
      "percentMatch" : 66,
      "validationNotes" : "House Number, Pre Directional, Street Name, Post Directional do not match.",
      "serviceExceptions" : null,
      "validatedAddress" : "1220 W COMMERCE ST",
      "addressLines" :
      {
        "addressLine" :
        [
          "1220 W COMMERCE ST"
        ]
      },
      "addressElements" :
      {
        "housePrefix" : null,
        "houseNumber" : "1220",
        "houseSuffix" : null,
        "streetPreDirectional" : "W",
        "streetName" : "COMMERCE",
        "streetSuffix" : "ST",
        "streetPostDirectional" : null,
        "building" : null,
        "floor" : null,
        "unit" : null,
        "route" : null,
        "box" : null,
        "additionalInfomation" : null,
        "designators" : null,
        "newConstruction" : null,
        "billingOnlyValidation" : null,
        "geoCoordinates" : null
      },
      "locality" :
      {
        "city" : "BUFFALO",
        "county" : "LEON",
        "state" : "TX",
        "country" : "USA",
        "postalCode" : "75831",
        "postalCodeExtension" : ""
      },
      "networkElements" :
      {
        "latitude" : 31.4558663,
        "longitude" : -96.0727934,
        "verticalCoordinates" : 8650.052836217625,
        "horizontalCoordinates" : 3801.6306343018737,
        "geoCode" : 3818500,
        "isIncorporated" : null,
        "lata" : "552",
        "rateCenter" : "BUFFALO",
        "wireCenterClli" : "BFLOTXXA",
        "wireCenterLat" : 31.459261437891254,
        "wireCenterLong" : -96.06751536371283,
        "switchClli" : "BFLOTXXAPS0",
        "ocn" : "1181",
        "ocnName" : "VALOR TELECOMM TX, LD-TX #2 DBA WINDSTREAM COMM SW",
        "ocnCategory" : "ILEC",
        "npa" : "430",
        "nxx" : "221",
        "equipmentType" : "17",
        "isWinILEC" : null,
        "cbsafpcode" : null
      }
    }
  ]
}'
AS json_data from dual)
SELECT JSON_TRANSFORM(JSON_DATA, KEEP '$.response[1]' RETURNING CLOB PRETTY ) 
    AS MODIFIED_JSON 
  FROM JSON_DOC
;

